FFT comparisons between g.USBamp software vs BCI2000 software
Update: I followed the instructions in g.USBamp Demo how to download the codes into Matlab   (btw the product page is at https://www.gtec.at/product/gusbamp-research/  )

Here is the exact Matlab code I used:
Channels=17; 
FileName='testwnpoint5hzhp.bin'; 
fid=fopen(FileName,'rb'); 
data=fread(fid,[Channels inf],'float32'); 
fclose(fid); 

P  = data(1,:);
signal=P';

signal=signal-mean(signal);
Fs = 4800; % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs; % Sampling period
L = size(signal, 1); % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T; % Time vector
X =  double(signal);
plot(t,X);
title('signal');
xlabel('t (seconds)');
ylabel('X(t)');

Y = fft(X);
P2 = abs(Y/L);
P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);

f = Fs/L*(0:(L/2));
plot(f,P1,'LineWidth',0.5);
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of X(t)');
xlabel('f (Hz)');
ylabel('|P1(f)|');


the Binary file saved direct from the g.USBamp Demo software is available at
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AUtGiqGeFef2twzi9nBdyIIdSnIsKnAH/view?usp=sharing
Is the Matlab code correct? Pls modify it so the plotting will be accurate if something is wrong. I just used the standard FFT plot code example. Since it is g.USBamp original software used, then the binary saved file data is more accurate than the one at BCI2000 which could be numerical artifacts of the processing producing the 958Hz peak, isn't it?
Below after the BCI2000 FFT is zoomed of that same BCI2000 FFT plot showing the noise floor didn't have any gap. Could it be processed that way by the BCI2000? How do you remove all the gap?
Original message:
I am using the g.USBamp, a $17500 Research grade amplifier used by major R&D centers and companies worldwide.
I have some questions about the output and FFT displayed. I compared the FFT outputs between the g.USBamp Demo software and the BCI2000 software. In both tests. I shorted the differential inputs of channel 1 (In+, In-, ground). I set sampling to 4800Hz, 0.5Hz High Pass and 1000Hz Low Pass using 8th order Butterworth filter and 58-62Hz Notch filter.
Here is the signal and FFT of the g.USBamp.


Why do the lower frequencies shift up? Do you call it baseline shift?
Here is the FFT from the output of the BCI2000 software. All settings the same. Including taken in same sitting and both within 10 minutes.

Zoomed of the above noise floor:

Why is there no shift of any kind in the BCI2000 output? Instead there is a 958Hz peak that is not seen using the g.USBamp software? What is the cause of the strange 958Hz peak?
Which FFT is the correct one (the one from g.USBamp software shown in the first figure or the BCI2000 software)?

Hi, first of all could you please plot both results with the same y-axis limits?

I used a generic Matlab code to run them and dont know how to adjust the Y axis. But let me know why the entire noise floor can rise up in the first one while the 2nd one has noise floor at bottom. And the origin of the 958Hz peak at 2nd. Tnx

I do not know why the ~ 1 KHz signal is showing up in the bottom FFT plot but not in the upper FFT plot.  There is also a lot of other spurious as you can see in the lower levels of the lower plot. However if you zoom in (using the magnifier with the plus sign in it) at the lower levels, you can adjust the scale of both plots to be the same and you may likely see the same elevation in noise floor. This is the amplified noise which is then passed through a low pass filter and expected to appear this way.

pls see this zoomed plot https://a4.pbase.com/o12/60/7710960/1/174532631.K0NBZuM0.zoomlowerfft.JPG  there is no gap to the bottom.. could the 958Hz be numerical processing artifact? BCI2000 may have done something to it to make it stick all the way to the floor

Not really an answer but to long for a comment.
That's most likely  pilot error on your part but it's hard to tell without looking at the details of what you are doing. None of these look right but it's hard to tell.
A few tips

Look at the data sheet of the amp (website seems to be down). Do
their quoted noise floor match the time domain  signal in graph
number 1 ? Don't proceed to FFTs until your time domain waveform matches what the data sheet says or you fully understand why it doesn't.
This may be require you to hunt down noise sources in your analog setup: grounding scheme, cleanliness of power supplies, electromagnetic radiation sources, shielding, etc.
Start with one software packet. Don't proceed until you fully understand what it does and how to use it
I suggest putting correct units on your Y-axes. I can't read the
first one the other 2 don't have any. This will require to study how
exactly the software packages scale the DFT, what FFT length, what
window, what averaging, etc.
Ideally you would start with most simple FFT and slowly work your way up through post processing (filters, averaging, windows, etc)
With the info in bullet 5 you should be able to calculate the total noise in both frequency and the time domain. Don't proceed until this two numbers match
Now start adding a sine wave of a known frequency and amplitude. Make sure that the wave form and spectrum are correct and that THD numbers from both domains match.
Once you get that sorted  out, you can proceed bringing up the next software package.

Bringing up an expensive measurement amplifier is a fair bit of work, but it pays back in spades later once you get clean and repeatable measurement results. Bad or compromised data really doesn't help anyone. I know many labs who will run a full calibration and validation test before EVERY lab use of the instrument. In many cases this is mostly automated since a) makes it quick and easy do run and b) reduces the risk of human operator error.
EDIT: after taking a quick look at the signals

You have a strong switching artifact at the beginning of all time domain wave forms. I suggest adjusting your data capture method.  I don't a 15k unit should be doing this, so it's probably a configuration error. For now, you can just cut off the first 1000 or so samples and the spectrum looks a lot more reasonable.
I couldn't figure out what units the data is in
You have a moderate DC bias, I suggest subtracting it out (there is no obvious drift)
There is a LOT going on on the other 16 channels so some of your artifacts may be cross talk. I suggest shorting ALL inputs.


Please see the major edit with the product url specs, google drive file of the binary data saved, Matlab codes exactly used. the output should be accurate, isn't it? kindly check the Matlab code. i just used the standard FFT plot example code. But it should work, isn't it.  Yes the noise of the time domain plot is correct.

That URL is marketing babble, not a data sheet. You need technical specs like SNR, dynamic range, THD, preamp configuration,  calibration & scaling, voltage ranges , etc. Unless you understand what signal you need to expect, you can't check whether the signal you get into Matlab is correct or not

@Jtl: I took a look at your signals, found a lot of problems, and updated my answer. Did you not look at them yourself?

Thanks. I skipped the first 1000 samples and the noise curve is flat to bottom now..Do you know what kind of numerical artifact of processing can create the 958Hz peak at the BCI2000 software? in general, how can processing artifact create new frequencies?

@Jtl: sorry, I keep repeating myself here. It looks like your data capture itself is bad. Fix this first and don't do any processing until your data comes in clean.

I disconnected the ground between channel 1-4 from channel 5-16 and the 958Hz peak disappears. It could be crosstalk but i wonder why crosstalk can produce 958Hz noise. Tnx for the suggestion.
